# If Statement Excel Wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have two columns, Ref and Text. I need formula to know if text column has *dispute* word in it. All the same reference should show "Yes" in dispute column.
e.g. in below case first 4 cells in dispute column should show "Yes"

```
Reference   Text                    Dispute
5558012265  Dispute 5004710 06/01   
5558012265                          
5558012265  Dispute 5004710 06/01   
5558012265                          
5551007340      
5551007340
```

Please help I will be very thankful to you

Comment: "I need a formula written for me" type questions are typically off-topic on Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a helper column.  Assuming your data is in cells A2:A10, enter the following as an array formula<sup>1</sup> in C2, and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A2&"*dispute*",A$2:A$10&B$2:B$10,0),"Dispute",""),"")
```

This searches for the value in cell A2 concatenated with the word "dispute" (case-insensitive). The wildcard (*) causes `MATCH` to ignore anything after the word "dispute" (such as " 5004710 06/01.")

The `IF` function outputs "Dispute" if found.  If not found, `MATCH` returns an error, and `IFERROR` is used to ignore that error.

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> Array formulas are entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks Rick,It gives me dispute information only if “dispute” word in the beginning of the text field. It’s doesn't work if I have some other text in front of “dispute”. E.g. “123 dispute” “abc dispute”. 

Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an auxiliary column ("C") like this (assuming ref is "A" and text is "B"):

```
=1*IFERROR(FIND("dispute",lower(B2))>0,FALSE)
```

and put this in the "dispute" colum:

```
=IF(SUMIF(A$2:A$10,A2,C$2:C$10)>0,"Dispute","")
```

Comment: It gives me answer only for B2 and B4, Where dispute exist in Text column. However I want a formula to show "Yes" in all first 4 cells, because reference (first column) is same in first 4 columns.

Comment: ok, so I didn't understant the question correctly at first... will update answer

Comment: edited answer again (got order of arguments to "FIND" wrong...)

Comment: Thanks for the effort you are putting to help me.. I have added little bit more data in it. e.g. I have put 2558999 in ref (A8 to A10)  and put "Dispute" in B8. I would expect to come "dispute" in all cell from D8 to D10 (D column is now dispute column because we have added C column), however it's showing only in D8 cell not in all D8 to D10.

Comment: And can we make it without case sensitive so that it can find all dispute related text references?

Comment: Thanks, Did you manage to look in to what I have asked before.  that is "" I have added little bit more data in it. e.g. I have put 2558999 in ref (A8 to A10) and put "Dispute" in B8. I would expect to come "dispute" in all cell from D8 to D10 (D column is now dispute column because we have added C column), however it's showing only in D8 cell not in all D8 to D10.""